# "The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found" Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a simple app in Xamarin Android with Xamarin Forms using Visual Studio, however I keep getting this error everytime I try to build. I have double checked my references which should contain the Portable project, as well as made sure I have the latest version of Xamarin.Forms. What could I still be missing that would give this error?

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using App2;

using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace App2.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App2", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity :
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity // superclass new in 1.3
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App()); // method is new in 1.3
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the source of the error! If anyone else is struggling, try updating Xamarin.Forms using NuGet Packages for Solution. I was only using the Package Manager Console which was not giving me the latest version.

Comment: Updating Xamarin.Forms (from 2.0 to 2.3.4) in Portable class library worked for me. I am using VS2017 Preview 2.

Comment: Also, I got a downgrade warning in VS from the iOS project. The reason is the iOS project doesn't have a build configuration by default as a part of the solution.

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I found there is a bug with Visual Studio 2017 when making a cross platform Xamarin Form app with the generated code if there is a dash in the filename.

It looks like it tries to snake case the title and then complains about not finding that file.

For example, for "my-project", it starts looking for "my_project" in some areas of the generated code.

Using a project name with no symbols seems to solve the issue.

Comment: My god this is still an issue? Thank you so much I was ripping my hair out trying to figure out why my FRESH project wasn't building

Comment: Same happens with last version of Visual Studio for Mac, thank you !

Comment: Just updated to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.5 And had this problem. I have a repo with dashes in the name... changed the name and voila. except that is a real pain.

Comment: This solved it for me. I'm using Visual Studio for Mac. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you're still having issues check to see that the PCL project is referenced under the references in the solution explore
[the refrences option in the solution explore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJmtQ.png)

- Right click on the references option and click add reference.
- in the dialogue box, select the PCL project and click okay.

this should solve the error

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the namespace you defined in pcl under which the class App() is created is defined in Android project. For example, If your pcl class App() is present under the namespace called App2, then you need to add this namespace in Android project as follows,
using App2;

Answer (score 2):

Check this out if the problem is still not resolved :

Go to

`project -> Reference - right click and select  -.> Add reference -> from left side`

`select Project -> solution -> then (check ) select Project name --> OK`
finish

Answer (score 0):

I was renaming the projects of the solution and had this same error. What I have done is delete the reference to the .Net Standard project and readded with the new name to the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

My case is really rare but I had the same issue and the problem was that I referenced two pcl projects that referenced Xamarin.Forms (one standard shared project and another my custom library with UI controls). Removing dependency to the second one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not related to Xamarin, but might help others in the future seeing the same error message. This was an ASP.NET 5.0 Blazor Web Assmebly project and I was developing using Visual Studio for Mac.

I got this error when I had renamed a project from `Foo` to `FooBar`.

It turns out, VS did not refactor the namespaces in any classes I created, so the root namespace was left as `Foo`, which was where the startup `Program` class was, yet the framework was searching for the `App.razor` file in the project root, which had been renamed to `FooBar`.

To fix this, I simply renamed the namespace of the `Program` class from `Foo` to `FooBar`.

Comment: I had the same issue with .Net 5, vscode and blazor webassembly. I could fix it by adding `@namespace YourProjectNamespace` to `App.razor`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the android and iOS projects could not find the PCL.
I had to import the PCL as a project into Android and iOS. Rebuild solution and you should be fine!